# Product created programmatically in Magento is not showing up in `cataloginventory_stock_status` untill I open and save the product?

Tags: magento

I created a product programmatically using the following code..

`

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$simpleProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');   
 $simpleProduct
//    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
    ->setAttributeSetId(4) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
    ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
    // ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
//    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
    ->setSku('simple') //SKU
    ->setName('test simple product') //product name
    ->setWeight(4.0000)
    ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
    ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
    ->setColor(4)
    ->setManufacturer(8) //manufacturer id
    ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
    ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
    ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
    ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
    ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
    ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
    ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
    ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
    ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
    ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
    ->setDescription('This is a long description')
    ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
    // ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
    ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
            'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
            'qty' => 999 //qty
        )
    )
    ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
    $simpleProduct->save();`
```

Now the product is successfully created and is shown in manage products tab in admin panel.

**The product is not shown in Home Page.** So I opened the product and saved without any modification.Now the product is visible.

Difference I found is Before saving the product is that the table `Cataloginventory Stock Status` did not had any record before but once I saved from admin panel,a new row is created.....

Can anyone HELP please...

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try explicitly forcing the reindex of the product?

```
$event = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->logEvent(
$simpleProduct,
$simpleProduct->getResource()->getType(),
Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE,
false
);

Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')
->getProcessByCode('cataloginventory_stock') 
->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)
->processEvent($event);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

after uploading product flush cache and do reindexing.